# Slow lookup and data loading in Vertica

Tags: database, pentaho, data-warehouse, vertica

I am evaluating Vertica 8.1. I am really happy with its performance at BI side. My reports are running 20 times faster. But it is very slow when it does lookup in the fact loading transformation and also when loading the dimension tables. More the lookup steps I have in a transformations, slower it gets. I have created a lot of projections (one for each column in the dimension tables). I am not using clustering feature of Vertica.

My dimension table surrogate keys are integers. When loading the dimension table, I check the table maximum and add 1 to it in the next row. By any chance, is that a problem? Because, the lookup and data loading with Pentaho is like 30ish rows per second. To load the dimensions, I am using `Dimension lookup/update` step for SCD Type 2, and to load the combination dimensions I am using `Combination lookup/update` step. I am loading the fact using `Vertica bulk loader`. I read the documentation on Vertica's website which was about connections and best practices using Pentaho with Vertica. But it didn't seem helpful.

Suggestions?

Comment: Please share the SQL used to load your dimension table.

Comment: I am using Pentaho Data Integration to do that. But the query should be 

INSERT INTO public.dim_scd2_test VALUES (0, 1,'1900-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp,'2199-12-31 23:59:59'::timestamp,  10000, 'no_status_available');

Comment: One row at a time? Extremely inefficient. Also, you should check how long this single row INSERT takes in Vertica...

Comment: I don't know what Pentaho does internally. But with postgres it loads at the rate of 2000 rows per second. How would you load the dimension tables?

Comment: It depends, of course. For sure not one row at a time. I would just rely on bulk loading and PUSHING DOWN transformations (when needed) into the database. You can expect millions (not thousands) of rows/second.

Comment: Pentaho Dimension lookup is extremely slow, there is nothing with the database, @Nikhil

Comment: @fenix: Oh ok! So, how should I populate SCD Type 2 using Pentaho?

Comment: @Nikhil One of the options is to lookup only the changed rows (since last update) against the dimension.

Comment: @fenix: But, even to do that I will need to scan the whole table, right?

Comment: Almost all ETL tools are very inefficient with their automated SCD maintenance functionality. The best workaround is to populate with a mass insert a staging table with identical structure as the SCD table with all affected rows, in the shape they should have at the end, and finally to run an optimized MERGE.

Comment: @Nikhil you don't, provide only the data that are recently updated to dimension lookup step. It would be slow as well, but still much faster that full table lookup.

Comment: You say that you have added many projections, one for each column in the dimension tables.  This will incur overhead when loading dimensions.

Comment: Even after dropping projections, it is taking a lot of time. I increased the memory of the VM where it is running and cores as well. But no change.